# How to access an SSD drive from a virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, ssd, virtualization

I'm using Xubuntu as the host OS and I've installed VirtualBox from the repositories. So I created a Windows XP 64 bit VM in VirtualBox, but I can't make it see the SSD device, which can be seen from Xubuntu. I've tried installing the VirtualBox additions, but still can't make it work.

Any help?

Comment: Pull up the Help and look under `Advanced storage configuration`, specifically "Access to entire physical hard disk". (By "hard disk" it really means block device.) Alternatively, punch [createrawvmdk](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk) into your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shared folder to your SSD, I recommend the following steps in your VM settings:

[image: Screenshot]

(note: Altough it's possible to access your SSD [directly](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#idp13436352), it's kinda risky).

Comment: Yes, but I want the guest OS (Windows XP 64-bit) to recognize it as an SSD device.